# Send Keypress to specific window/programm only

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, obs

I have a Script that toggle a source in SLOBS (OBS), how can I make it that the keypress get only send to OBS, mostly my games also react to the Hotkeys, maybe it's possible to get the keypress only send to OBS so that the game is not affected by it, is this possible my actual script:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 1800000
 Return

PressTheKey:
Send, {F24 down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {F24 up}

Sleep, 10000

Send, {F24 down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {F24 up}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ControlSendRaw](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm).